# Jump to tag in vim (Windows, Parallels)

Tags: windows, vim, parallels

I am using vim & gvim (version 7.4) in Windows under Parallels. I am trying to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to jump to tags under the cursor in help files but nothing happens. In gvim, I can double click on the tag and this works but I  would like to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

Does anybody have any ideas why this would not be working and how I can fix it? I would rather not remap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to some other key combination.

Comment: Apparently Parallels often causes problems with modifier keys. Does [this](http://kb.parallels.com/en/7072) help you?

Comment: Hi ohlec, thanks for the suggestion but this does not make a difference for me. I am using Parallels 9 so I used [this](http://kb.parallels.com/116994) article. It is strange because other CTRL+key combinations work fine e.g. CTRL+W to change window.

Comment: Objections to sharing part of the windows drive and using vim on the host side?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the suggestion but I have went with just remapping the keys using the tip [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Learn_to_use_help#Simplify_help_navigation). I would still like to know why CTRL+] does not work while other similar commands do (e.g. CTRL+W ] opens the tag in a new page) but I will forget about it for now!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I fixed it by uninstalling parallels tools. I now run it headless and connect with Microsoft Remote Desktop.